# How to display image thumbnails on the search results page?

Tags: images, search, post-thumbnails

Been trying to get images to appear on our search page, but only time i can get the two pieces of code to work it removes all of our sites formatting and style.
Am i missing something. :(

NEW Code Added -

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * search.php
 *
 * The search results template. Used when a search is performed.
 *
 */
get_header();
?>
<?php get_sidebar('top'); ?>
<?php
if (have_posts()) {
    theme_post_wrapper(
            array('content' => '<h4 class="box-title">' . sprintf(__('Search Results for: %s', THEME_NS), '<span class="search-query-string">' . get_search_query() . '</span>') . '</h4>'
            )
    );
    /* Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable */
    if (theme_get_option('theme_top_posts_navigation')) {
        theme_page_navigation();
    }
    /* Start the Loop */
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        get_template_part('content', 'search');
    }
    <div class="entry">
    <?php
    if(has_post_thumbnail()) { // check if the post Thumbnail
        the_post_thumbnail();
    }
    else {
        //your default img
    }
    the_excerpt(); //your short description
    ?>
    </div>
    /* Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable */
        if (theme_get_option('theme_bottom_posts_navigation')) {
        theme_page_navigation();
            }
        }
     else 
    {
        theme_404_content(
            array(
                'error_title' => __('Nothing Found', THEME_NS),
                'error_message' => __('Sorry, but nothing matched                               your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.', THEME_NS)
                )
        );
    }
    ?>
    <?php get_sidebar('bottom'); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Where are you adding that post thumbnail code? Post the code in context. You probably just have a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: Thanks S_ha_dum - I have tried everywhere i can think of that would be logical. Mainly adding the <div class="entry"> part just after the  - get_template_part('content', 'search');
    } - sorry to sound so daft but I have only recently started playing with this coding. Allan

Comment: Edit it into the question exactly as you have it please. I doubt want to guess.

Comment: Looks like there is a bunch of code outside the loop. Amiright?

Answer (score 0):

you should be adding your thumbnail code to the individual search template from the theme, which is noted:

```
get_template_part('content', 'search');
```

within that template is where you'll want to add your thumbnail code. if you can show that template code, we could help you further

Comment: Hi, following what you said above, i went at with a new angle, but still could not get it to function. Added the code below with everything in it. Hope I am doing this correctly - sorry it wont let me add the code as too many characters - :( the code is being added to the search.php file as far as im aware thats correct. Will try to change original code in original message above - :)

Comment: "template parts" don't have to be constructed the way you assume. The system is far more flexible than this answer suggests.